# Reply to Merry Christmas wishes

Tags: greetings, email

I have received an email with wishes for Merry Christmas and other information from my employer. I want to know if it is correct to respond in this way:

> Thank you for the information, Merry Christmas to you, too.

Comment: If your employer is wishing *for* other information, then you should actually be giving that information *to* them—not thanking them for it. But I'm guessing you didn't meant to phrase it that way in your question. You'd probably meant to say you received an email from your employer wishing you Merry Christmas and *giving you* some other information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a greeting message, which also contains some information.

Your response is just fine.

> Thank you for the information. Merry Christmas to you too.

Or you can also use:

> Thank you for informing. Merry Christmas to you too.

Comment: Ugo Mela says the message contained "wishes for Merry Christmas *and other information*". I think his original suggested response was probably fine.

Comment: Oh my bad. Totally missed that point!!